# NSDictionary returning same value for different keys

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsnumber

I have some Obj-C code that uses `NSNumber`s as keys in a dictionary.  I'd found a bug that I tracked down to some very strange behavior where if the dictionary is accessed using `NSDecimalNumber` (a subclass of `NSNumber`) it would always return the same element.  Here's a small program that exhibits the behavior and the NSLogs output the problem:

```
#define LONGNUMBER1 5846235266280328403
#define LONGNUMBER2 5846235266280328404
- (void) wtfD00d {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSNumber *key1 = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:LONGNUMBER1];
    NSNumber *key2 = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:LONGNUMBER2];
    dict[key1] = @"ONE";
    dict[key2] = @"TWO";

    NSNumber *decimalKey1 = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithLongLong:LONGNUMBER1];
    NSNumber *decimalKey2 = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithLongLong:LONGNUMBER2];
    NSString *value1 = dict[decimalKey1];
    NSString *value2 = dict[decimalKey2];

    NSLog(@"Number of entries in dictionary = %lu", (unsigned long)dict.count); // 2
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);  //  5846235266280328403 = ONE
                         //  5846235266280328404 = TWO
    NSLog(@"Value1 = %@, Value 2 = %@", value1, value2);   // Value1 = ONE, Value 2 = ONE
    NSLog(@"key2 = decimalKey2: %@", [key2 isEqual:decimalKey2] ? @"True" : @"False");  // key2 isEqual decimalKey2: True
    NSLog(@"decimalKey1 = decimalKey2: %@", [decimalKey1 isEqual:decimalKey2] ? @"True" : @"False");  // decimalKey1 isEqual decimalKey2: False
}
```

Notice that the 3rd log line shows that value1 and value2 are the same.  WHY does this happen?

This came up because we have a few fields in CoreData with type Decimal and they come out of CoreData as NSNumber.  We found that we had to play games to get around this strange behavior and I don't understand why it happens in the 1st place.  I'd love any insight anyone can offer as to why the failed lookups.

Comment: That's strange indeed. But `[key1 isEqual:decimalKey2]` returns TRUE.

Comment: Crazy!  Good find.  That's really weird how those 2 are equal.  Maybe that's the source of the behavior.

Comment: Also all numbers have the same hash value: `3063018850992016384`

Comment: @Cy-4AH I'd noticed that but that's not necessarily the problem.  Hashes aren't unique, they are just to speed lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that when `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber` are compared with each other, they are using `doubleValue` for comparison.

You can report bug in apple for that

I can suggest only to avoid `NSNumber<->NSDecimalNumber` comparison and use here:

```
NSString *value1 = dict[@(decimalKey1.longLongValue)];
NSString *value2 = dict[@(decimalKey2.longLongValue)];
```

Comment: This is what we did for a workaround but I like your explanation of WHY it's doing what it's doing.  I guess I'll report a bug for it.  Ty!